# How to find one of every values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

basically I want to list one of every value like this.

data I have:

```
aaa
aaa
bbb
aaa
ccc
bbb
ddd
ccc
ddd
aaa
```

the output that I want:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

how can I do this?
I can't find anything on google because I don't know the right keyword to search.

Comment: Remove duplicates?

Comment: if you have the dynamic array formula, UNIQUE()